# Result of 'File.mkdirs()' is ignored

Tags: java, android

This is my Code inside `myDir.mkdirs();` this code show me that warning of Result of `File.mkdirs()` is ignored.

I try to fix this Warning but I failed.

```
   private void saveGIF() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gif Save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String filepath123 = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            try {
                File myDir = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()) + "/" + "NewyearGIF");enter code here

    //My Statement Code This Line Show Me that Warning

 myDir.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(myDir, "NewyearGif_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif");
                filepath123 = file.getPath();
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(this.ivDrawable);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] img = new byte[AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT];
                while (true) {
                    int current = bis.read();
                    if (current == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    baos.write(current);
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
            mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath123)));
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
```

Comment: `Result of 'File.mkdirs()' is ignored`. Yes. By YOU! You are not looking at the return value.

Comment: Docs says,
>You may mentioning deeper path of the file, but, there is no need all the parent directories need to be created. Because, some may created already. some is not. So, even it fails to create already existence directory, it will create non existence directory which will give success result. it will give true result when all necessary directory created. So, there is a need to check the boolean condition in this scenario.

Answer (score 20):

The method `mkdirs` has a `boolean` return value, which you didn't use.

```
 boolean wasSuccessful = myDir.mkdirs();
```

The create operation returns a value, which indicates if the creation of the directory was successful. For example, the result value `wasSuccessful` can be used to display an error when it is false.

```
if (!wasSuccessful) { 
    System.out.println("was not successful."); 
}
```

From the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) about the `boolean` return value:

> true if and only if the directory was created, along with all
>   necessary parent directories; false otherwise

Comment: If the directory already exists, then it returns false. This isn't necessarily an error, as your code shows.

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
if(myDirectory.exists() || myDirectory.mkdirs()) {
   // Directory was created, can do anything you want
}
```

or you can just remove the warning using:

```
@SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
```

The `mkdirs` method checks if file exists but returns false if the directory was already created so you should check one more time using first method.

Answer (score 6):

```
File CDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), IMPORT_DIRECTORY);
if (!CDir.exists()) {
    boolean mkdir = CDir.mkdir();
    if (!mkdir) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Directory creation failed.");
    }
}
```

mkdir return a Boolean value. we need to catch the return value from mkdir .Replace your code with this and check  (warning of Result of File.mkdirs() is ignored.)  will be gone

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind the return-value of mkdir is, that every IO-Operation could fail and your program should react to this situation.

Comment: How? I use File.delete() for example. I usually don't care if it didn't work because I can't do anything about it. Maybe somebody/something else deleted it before I could do it. So what...

Comment: @TheincredibleJan I agree with you that I usually do not care. I would think of this as an option you could react on (in rare cases).

Answer (score 3):

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"NewyearGIF");
if(!myDirectory.exists()) {
   myDirectory.mkdirs(); 
}else{
   // Directory already exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question but still, the simplest way I've found is:

```
File imageThumbsDirectory = getBaseContext.getExternalFilesDir("ThumbTemp");

if(imageThumbsDirectory != null) {
    if (!imageThumbsDirectory.exists()) {
        if (imageThumbsDirectory.mkdir()) ; //directory is created;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put this code:

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"NewyearGIF");
if(!myDirectory.exists()) {
   myDirectory.mkdirs(); 
}else{
   // Directory already exist
}
```

If application running in above `Lollipop`, then you need to add runtime permission for storage.

Comment: `myDirectory.mkdirs(); `. YOU are also ignoring the result value. The return value. It should be `if ( !myDirectory.mkdirs()){ Toast(sorry could not make directory); return false;}`

Comment: @JayminBhadani You are testing on which os Lollipop or marshmallow?

Comment: @JayminBhadani Did you allow storage permission from settings>apps>appname>permissions ?